# How to connect to MySQL on 3307 port in ruby dbi

Tags: mysql, ruby

In Ruby

db = DBI.connect("DBI:Mysql:database=db1:host=dbhostname:port=3307", "username", "password")

isn't working for me

using the same details in a direct mysql connection in the command line does...?

What am I missing to get the connection on port 3307 ???

I get the error:

Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (DBI::DatabaseError)

Comment: It might be a good idea to use single quotes on your strings in case something is being interpreted unexpectedly.

Comment: tried that and no difference, also tried host=dbhostname;port=3307

Comment: 'DBI:Mysql:host=hostname;database=dbname;port=3307' worked in the end for me

Answer (score 2):

changed order

`DBI:Mysql:host=hostname;database=dbname;port=3307` worked for reason I don't really know.